# How to list all Private AMIs in AWS CloudFormation Parameters for Service Catalog

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-service-catalog

How I can list all Private AMI in dropdown of Service Catalog.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : 2010-09-09
Description: "simple web layer"
Parameters:
  ImageId:
    Description: 'web Layer'
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>'
    AllowedPattern: "^[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
    Default: ami-244333
    OwnerId: '836749474673'
```

> Error : Invalid Parameter property 'ownerid'

Answer (score 1):

From [Parameters - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html):

> `AWS::EC2::Image::Id`
>   An Amazon EC2 image ID, such as ami-0ff8a91507f77f867. Note that the AWS CloudFormation console **doesn't show a drop-down list** of values for this parameter type.

According to this documentation, it is not possible to obtain a drop-down list of AMIs. There is also no mention of the ability to specify an `OwnerId` to limit possible values for the AMI being entered.

However, I'm **not sure** whether the same rules would apply to the Service Catalog UI.